# Function Level linking in gcc

Tags: gcc, static-linking

I search in old threads. But didn't find any thread answering my question.

Is gcc support function level linking like vc++ ?

if yes what option should I give to link object files and library ?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like gcc does not support function level linking directly. You can pass `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` command line options to reduce resulting executable size. Look also this [link](https://ribosome.helixcommunity.org/2005/devdocs/FuncLevelLinking.html#head-44ed3c22827ec51a72f9a6de4535342d215e60fd) for more info.